# how to use if condition in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to Kivy and python , I want to set font size of label depending on screen size, also with some condition in Kivy, How do I achive it ?
Is conditional syntax like if else can be used in kivy file ?

Comment: Please have a look at their docs.. It's describing everything very well.. https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can very well use Python code in your .kv file. For example

```
Label:
   text: 'Changed' if myswitch.active else 'On the switch to change text'
```